Are there any examples of Parent/Child queries using Spring Data Opensearch?
I am using:

Spring Data Opensearch Starter v1.5.0

Currently I have a custom configuration file in which I extend AbstractOpenSearchConfiguration and override opensearchClient() to create a RestHighLevelClient. I need to query Opensearch using the HasChild and HasParent queries. Is there a way to do this using RestHighLevelClient?
